# how can I save a scikit-learn confusion matrix as png

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How can I save a confusion matrix as png? I've saw this answer:

[How to save Confusion Matrix plot so that I can call it for future reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691216/how-to-save-confusion-matrix-plot-so-that-i-can-call-it-for-future-reference)

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

y_true = [0,1,1,1,0]
y_pred = [1,1,1,1,0]

IC = type('IdentityClassifier', (), {"predict": lambda i : i, "_estimator_type": "classifier"})

cm = plot_confusion_matrix(IC, y_pred, y_true, normalize='true',  values_format='.2%')
    
cm.figure_.savefig('confusion_matrix.png')
```

The result that I'm getting is just a black png image.

Comment: what library is `plot_confusion_matrix` from?  What is returned from it?

Comment: @James scikit learn

Comment: What is your scikit-learn version?

Comment: No sure how you are running the code, but I have seen that the background color set in your environment effects the png. see what happens if you define it first: cm.figure_.savefig('confusion_matrix.png',facecolor='xkcd:mint green')

Comment: @Kilian I'm just getting a green picture

Comment: @desertnaut The scikit-learn version is 0.24.2.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should update sklearn to the latest version and then use:

```
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay


y_true = [0,1,1,1,0]
y_pred = [1,1,1,1,0]

IC = type('IdentityClassifier', (), {"predict": lambda i : i, "_estimator_type": "classifier"})

cm=ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_estimator(IC, y_pred, y_true, normalize='true',  values_format='.2%')

cm.figure_.savefig('confusion_matrix.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

A concise version

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
y_true = [0,1,1,1,0]
y_pred = [1,1,1,1,0]
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm)
disp.plot().figure_.savefig('confusion_matrix.png')
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.